# Can we have an app with both an .odex file outside the apk and also classes.dex file inside the apk?

Tags: android, apk, dex

I have an android application, which contain an .odex file and also 3 classes.dex files . It is a large application .I do not have the source code for the app .

My understaning is that : When an application is optimized it will move the application code outside the apk in a file *.odex .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self Answered :

We can specify option , ‘nostripping’ with "LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false " if pre-optimization should not strip the classes.dex file from the apk or jar file. Normally this file is stripped since it’s no longer needed after pre-optimization, but this last option is necessary to allow third-party APK signatures to remain valid.

So we will have both classes.dex and also *.odex files created .